# sum of a part over all compositions of fixed length

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

The number of solutions for $x_1+...+x_k = n$ for positive integers $x_1,...,x_k,n$ is given by $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, which is the number of $k$-compositions of $n$.

Now we take the sum over all of those:

> $\sum_{x_1+...+x_k = n}x_1$

which is supposedly to be equal to

> $\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}.$

This is a product of the number of compositions with the mean value of a part, but I don't understand (mathematically) why

Comment: Notice that you may also interpret this in term of probabilities : the expectation of the first step (among the k ones that sum up to n) is... well, unsurprisingly, n/k (by exchangeability of the increments) ! This is however an unnecessary burden to formalize this exactly in your case, and this amounts exactly to write the argument by Dominik below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $ S(i) = \sum_{x_1+...+x_k = n}x_i $.

Note that $S(i) = S(j)$ for every $i,j \in \{1,...,k\} $

$\sum_{i=1}^k S(i) = \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{x_1+...+x_k = n}x_i = \sum_{x_1+...+x_k = n}\sum_{i=1}^k x_i =\sum_{x_1+...+x_k = n}n = n{ n-1 \choose k-1 } $

On the other hand

$\sum_{i=1}^k S(i) = k\cdot S(1) $

So:

$S(1) = \frac{n}{k}{ n-1 \choose k-1 } $